# Чем отличаются следующие вызовы: “dict.get(a, {})” и “dict.get(a) or {}”?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Пусть dic - некоторый словарь, "a" - ключ, по которому мы хотим достать значение из этого словаря. Он может как присутствовать в словаре, так и отсутствовать.
 Чем отличаются следующие вызовы: `dic.get(a, {})` и `dic.get(a) or {}`?

В случае c `dic.get(a, {})` вопросов нет.

А вот с `dic.get(a) or {}`, не могу уложить в голове, почему возращает {}, если ключа **a** нет в словаре?

Пример:

```
dic = {}
a = "key"

print(dic.get(a) or {})  # {}
print(dic.get(a, {}))    # {}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Потому что, если ключа нет в словаре, то метод get вернёт `None`, и у вас по сути получается выражение вида `None or {}`

Comment: Тогда при `None or {}` результат ведь должен быть False, поскольку bool(None) => False, bool({}) => False. False or False => False

Comment: Не должен, никто нигде никакой bool() не делает, оператор `or` просто возвращает правое значение (то есть ваш {}), если слева от него стоит ложное значение (например None)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Применение `print(dic.get(a) or {})` опасно в ситуациях когда `dic = {"key":0}`, и также `""`,`False`, `()`, `[]` и т.д. Результатом будет `{}` и это может нарушить логику или улучшить её. При отсутствии "key" или присутствии логически труёвого значения результат одинаковый.

Comment: Думаю, «опасно» не самое удачное слово, я часто так делаю специально, чтобы избавиться от falsy-значений в словаре

Comment: @andreymal тоже так делаю, особенно когда дергаю json из sql ) я не запрещаю так делать, но смена типа в структуре....